# Компилятор избавляется от цикла

Tags: c, ассемблер, оптимизация, gcc

Рассматриваю оптимизацию под названием "cнижение мощности"

```
k2 = 4 * j5; 
for( i = 0; i <=5;i++) 
ivector4[ i ] = i * 2;
```

Запуская его без оптимизационных ключей ,цикл на месте

```
movl j5(%rip), %eax 
sall $2, %eax 
movl %eax, k2(%rip) 
movl $0, i(%rip) 
jmp .L4 
.L5: 
movl i(%rip), %eax 
movl i(%rip), %edx 
addl %edx, %edx 
cltq 
movw %dx, ivector4(%rax,%rax) 
movl i(%rip), %eax 
addl $1, %eax 
movl %eax, i(%rip) 
.L4: 
movl i(%rip), %eax 
cmpl $5, %eax 
jle .L5
```

А как только запустил с оптимизацией -O2, цикл пропадет

```
movw %r9w, ivector4(%rip) 
movw %r10w,ivector4+2(%rip) 
movw %r11w, ivector4+4(%rip) 
movl j5(%rip), %eax 
sall $2, %eax 
movl %eax, k2(%rip) 
movl $6, %eax 
movw %ax, ivector4+6(%rip) 
movl $8, %eax 
movw %ax, ivector4+8(%rip) 
movl $10, %eax 
movw %ax, ivector4+10(%rip)
```

Как вернуть цикл и не лишиться оптимизаций , ведь смысл этой оптимизации не в избавлении от цикла

Comment: Попробуйте с `-fno-unroll-loops`. Не факт, что поможет, но вдруг...

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, не сработало:(

Comment: В крайнем случае придется вынести эту инициализацию в раздельно компилируемую функцию передать границу цикла в ее аргументе

Comment: @avp, что значит раздельно компилируемую ? то есть в другой файл ?

Comment: Да, в отдельном файле.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414632/how-to-tell-gcc-never-unroll-a-loop#comment45164307_28414632

Comment: Можно попытаться объявить переменные с помощью детективы `volatile __asm__` при этом вроде оптимизация к ним не применяется, но надо тестировать с разными значениями ключа оптимизации.

Answer (score 0):

> Как вернуть цикл и не лишиться оптимизаций , ведь смысл этой оптимизации не в избавлении от цикла

При оптимизации компиллятор старается избавиться от ветвлений в коде и связанных с ними ошибок предсказания ветвлений. В циклах же на каждой итерации происходит проверка некоторого условия и ветвление кода. Поэтому при оптимизации циклы могут быть развёрнуты. Именно этот цикл:

```
for( i = 0; i <=5;i++) 
ivector4[ i ] = i * 2;
```

пропал по той причине, что все элементы ivector4 могут быть вычислены ещё на этапе компилляции, и просто подставлены во время исполнения. Оптимизированный ассемблерный код именно это и делает.